# Cannot assign value of type 'NSDictionary?' to type 'String?'

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

Below is my code (Swift 4.2.1) for getting response from API.But while calling it showing some error as,

> Cannot assign value of type 'NSDictionary?' to type 'String?'

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
   guard let data = data, error == nil else {
      return
   }
   let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
   print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
   do {
    let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary
     print(jsonResponse!)
     responsevalue = jsonResponse

     let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: self.responsevalue, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
     let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok",style: .default)
     {(ACTION)in
     }
     alert1.addAction(action1)
     self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }catch let parsingError {
        print("Error", parsingError)

        let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: parsingError as? String, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok",style: .default)
         {(ACTION)in
         }
         alert1.addAction(action1)
         self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
         }
       }
      task.resume()
```

Comment: responsevalue = jsonResponse, Here I am getting error,Cannot assign value of type 'NSDictionary?' to type 'String?'

Comment: In which line you got the error message

Comment: JSON RESPONSE:  responseString = Optional("{\"status\":\"500\",\"msg\":\"Incorrect Username or Password\"}")
{
    msg = "Incorrect Username or Password";
    status = 500;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `NSDictionary`. Use `[String: Any]`. You need to get the message string from the dictionary to show in the alert.

```
let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
print(jsonResponse)
responsevalue = jsonResponse
guard let message = jsonResponse["msg"] as? String else {//Use the key from json
    return
}
let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
```

In else part instead of using parsingError, use parsingError.localizedDescription

```
let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: parsingError.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
```

Answer (score 0):

as the error says `Cannot assign value of type 'NSDictionary?' to type 'String?'`. You are assigning NSDictionary to a variable who's type is String.

You need to change the original declaration of `responseString` to NSDictionary or your another variable to store your NSDictionary.